# Vagrant Machine stopped working

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, vagrant, homestead

I was using Homestead and vagrant for Laravel, everything was working fine until this morming when I tried to up the machine and work. 
i'm getting this error :

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 80 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 443 (guest) => 44300 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 3306 (guest) => 33060 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 5432 (guest) => 54320 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

Anyone can help me fix this issue without reinstalling all over again?

What I have tried :

- Restarting my computer
- Closing some application
- Deleting the VM
- Shutting off my Firewall

[VagrantFile content](http://pastebin.com/cp1mq8UP)

Comment: Are your ports free for Vagrant? Is your firewall enabled?

Comment: @Schellingerht I would tell you yes if I was 100% sure, but it was working last weeks. Don't know what could block vagrant

Comment: You can try to enable gui to see if you can spot what happens when it boots. `vm.gui = true`

Comment: The same... `==> default: VM not created. Moving on...`

Answer (score 1):

it look like your vagrant has problem accessing your VM using the private-key:

1. after the error-message, try to enter vagrant using the command `vagrant ssh`

--> if everything work well without having to enter password then the error is probably somewhere else (see the recommended setting using `config.vm.boot_timeout`)

2. maybe your private-key is not in the `known_hosts`  list of you VM

   2.1  back-up the private key in your workstation

a) As default, when using UBUNTU-OS, the file is located at `~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key`

b) You can also run the command `vagrant ssh-config` after `vagrant up`, in order to retrieve the exact location of the private_key in use)

2.2 delete the file and restart vagrant

`vagrant reload` or `vagrant reload --provision`

vagrant will try to regenerate a new private key for you.

3. Edited

According to the vagrantfile you have added:
You should also configure the network similar to the following example (remove the # and check if the content of your vagrantfile look like the example bellow):

```
MY_IP_ADDRESS = '10.11.12.15'

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

    config.vm.box = "base"
    config.vm.network :private_network, ip: MY_IP_ADDRESS
    config.ssh.forward_agent = true

end
```

4. You should check the box you are using, maybe the box does not exists

example `"hashicorp/precise64"`

please check the vagrant-documentation @ https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/boxes.html

Comment: `$ vagrant ssh`
`VM must be created before running this command. Run 'vagrant up' first.`

Comment: It seems that my Vagrant machine is not there anymore. Or is not found, on really know how this work behind-the-scene
`$ vagrant reload --provision`
`==> default: VM not created. Moving on...`

Comment: can you provide the content of your vagrant file?
if you have Virtualbox, u can easily check if your box is running

Comment: See the edited post to see if i got the right content

Comment: from which directory do you run `vagrant up` ?
you should see there a file named `Vagrantfile`

Comment: Done. When I start vagrant `==> default: Box 'base' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...` and then `An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

Couldn't open file /C:/Users/pierl/base
`

Comment: check the 4. possibility in my answer